# Does the wavelenth of matter waves depend upon the kinetic energy of the particle or object?

Tags: particle-physics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, matter

Do the properties of the waves (wavelength,frequency) emitted by a particle or  object depend upon the velocity, or as to say its kinetic energy? Is the De Broglie equation $E = h \nu $ applicable to matter waves as well?

Answer (score 1):

These are two different questions.

> Does the properties of the waves(wavelenth,frequency) emitted by a particle or an object depend upon the velocity

Yes, according to relativity, the emission lines of atoms depend on their velocity; it is the  [relativistic Doppler effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect) Here the wavelength is the wavelength of the electromagnetic wave emitted by an electron falling on a lower-energy orbital, for example.

> is the de-broglie equation E = h(v) applicable to matter waves

The relation is $E=h\nu$ and also applies to the matter waves, that are described by Schroedinger equation. But the corresponding $\nu$ has little to do with the wavelength of an emitted radiation.

Comment: As ν = c / λ, this means that the energy of an object is inversely related to its wavelenth,how correct is it?

Comment: This is true only for electromagnetic waves. For matter waves, ruled by Schroedinger equation, $\lambda$ is connected with $p$. Basically, this is because matter cannot move at the speed of light, moreover it has a mass, which must enter in the relation.

Comment: λ is related with velocity as λ = h/mv , wavelenth is still inverse to the velocity of the object (even for matter waves)?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. However, I would not say that the relation between $\lambda$ and $\nu$ is the same for electromagnetic waves and matter waves. In the first case, the involved speed is $c$, which is a physical constant and not a property of the wave, while in the second case there is a dependence on mass. Moreover, the relations between $\nu$ and $k=1/\lambda$ are different (linear in one case, square in the second).

Comment: Okay,does it hold any physical significance,assume this that, the velocity of an object is increased as such that it's wavelenth becomes equal to that of radio waves, is it doable?

Comment: Radio waves have a wavelength of the order of meters. In order to make a matter wave with such a long wave length, the particle must be extremely slow. Practically, this is not feasible, as the usual thermal motion gives much shorter wavelengths. Anyway, assuming that we have a matter wave with wavelength 1 cm, its frequency will be different from the frequency of the electromagnetic wave with same wavelength.

Comment: So ,even close to absolute zero ,the wavelenth would be much smaller than radio waves or long waves?

Comment: Let's see. $p=h\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$, thus $\lambda=h\frac{2\pi}{p}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{2mE}}$. We take $m$=500 keV (the electron) and $E=0.025 eV$ (thermal energy at roon temperature). We get 47 nm. At 1 K we go to approximately 1 um. At 500 nK we are at 1 mm. So, technically it is very hard but not too far from feasible to make a matter wave with wavelength similar to radio waves. But please check the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

1- Matter wave is not emitted by the particle, but it is a probability density wave-function. If you calculated the amplitude of this function, squared it, and integrated the result over a certain volume, it will give you the probability to find the particle within this volume

2- Yes, Total Energy (rest energy + kinetic energy)= $hf$, where $\lambda f = u $, and $u$ is the speed of the matter wave
$u$ is higher than light speed as it is the speed on a mathematical function, not a physical object, energy or information.

The relation between $u$ and $v$ is:

$C^2= uv$, where $v$, is the particle speed, and C is the speed of light in free space.

Comment: So ,matter waves are nothing but visualation tool to understand phenomenon like electron diffraction,and these waves doesn't  really exist in ordinary space. ?

Comment: It is not only about diffraction, but something like that. Personally I consider it existing, but mathematically with some physical aspects like speed and distribution through space.